# .then() ordering with promises

Tags: javascript, promise

How come in my `.then()` chain `printer.done()` isn't displaying my message?

`printer.done()` is supposed to display a message template.

```
   .then(() => {
    const whileHeapList = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(new Date());
            console.log(1);
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(2);
                console.log(new Date());
            }, 5000)
        }, 5000);
    };
    whileHeapList();
    }).then(() => {
        printer.done()
    });
```

What I want my code to do is log 1, wait 5 seconds log 2, THEN print out the `printer.done()` template message

Right now this is the output:

```
** TEMPLATE **

2017-01-30T04:19:54.111Z
1
2
2017-01-30T04:19:59.118Z
```

Comment: your code in the top `.then` doesn't return a promise to wait on, therefore, `printer.done` will execute almost immediately

Comment: @JaromandaX if i had `return new Promise(whileHeapList)` instead of `whileHeapList()` I get the 1,2 and time logs but the template is not displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the second `.then` to wait for the second `setTimeout` to complete, you will need to return a promise from the first `.then` that resolves once the second `setTimeout` fires

```
.then(function () {
    var whileHeapList = function whileHeapList() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) { // added
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(new Date());
                console.log(1);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log(2);
                    console.log(new Date());
                    resolve(); // added
                }, 5000);
            }, 5000);
        }); // added
    };
    return whileHeapList(); // added a return
}).then(function () {
    printer.done();
});
```

or, using the attempted code in yor comment

```
.then(function () {
    var whileHeapList = function whileHeapList(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(new Date());
            console.log(1);
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(2);
                console.log(new Date());
                resolve(); // added
            }, 5000);
        }, 5000);
    };
    return new Promise(whileHeapList);
}).then(function () {
    printer.done();
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the template gets printed FIRST and then the rest. I'm trying to print the 1,2 `and Date()` first and then the template. Not sure why this is happening =/. I thought the last `.then()` is executed only when the `.then()` before it finishes

Comment: this code will log, 1, 2 and only then will `printer.done()` execute ... make sure you take not of **every return** in the code - the problem probably exists because the code you posted is vastly different from the code you actually use - as the nested timeouts in your code serve no useful purpose ... if you want .then to "wait" for some asynchronous code in the previous `.then` you have to return a Promise that resolves when the asynchronous completes

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a sleep function and chain with then

```
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

...    

.then(() => sleep(5000))
.then(() => console.log(1, new Date()))
.then(() => sleep(5000))
.then(() => console.log(2, new Date()))
.then(() => printer.done())
```